# Why are verbs used as nouns?

Tags: verbs, nouns

Why are there so many verbs out there that are used as nouns?

Examples:

- Produce (lettuce, tomatoes, etc.)
- Preserve (strawberry preserves)
- Practice (law practice)
- Trust (bank trust)
- Seasoning (salt, pepper)

There are other nouns that seem to be hi-jacked too...

- Premiums (insurance invoice)
- Customs (taxes)
- Periodicals (publications)

Comment: Why? Because it is useful?

Comment: I don't recognise _seasoning_, _premiums_, _customs_ or _periodicals_ as verbs. No doubt they all could be, but I seem to be missing some of your point.

Comment: By the way, _produce_, _preserve_ and _practice_ were all verbs before they were nouns. _Trust_ and _season_ were nouns first.

Comment: Remember that in Britain many verbs change slightly when converting to nouns. For example; Lawyers practise law in their law practices, and advise their clients with sound advice.

Comment: Simply because it's possible in English. The structures in which nouns and verbs are used are so different that you won't have any difficulty with it. And when there is ambiguity then I would say it is due to an unskilled writer who can't avoid ambiguities.

Comment: I was not implying 'Premiums' and 'Customs' are verbs.  They are nouns that took on a different, perhaps new meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A vast number of words can be both verbs and nouns.  You have listed only a few.  Additionally verbs can **act as** nouns in a sentence by using them in *gerund* form.
Verbs can also act as adjectives, for example, *participles*.